# Java 8 nested null check and access first element

Tags: java

How can I convert the below legacy java code to use Optional :

```
if (outer != null
        && outer.getInnerMethod() != null
        && outer.getInnerMethod().isAllowed()) {
   Obj value = outer.getInnerMethod().getSomethingElse();
}
```

Using something like Optional.ofNullable took me till here -

```
Optional.ofNullable(Outer.getOuter)
        .map(Outer::getInnerMethod)
        .map(SomethingElse::isAllowed)
        .ifPresent(.. );
```

But ifPresent will not have access to the outer object. What would be the cleanest way to transform something like this ?

Comment: Its kind of a 6 line unit test candidate to see what will happen.

Comment: You are mapping to `isAllowed()`, which yields an `Optional<Boolean>`. You want to use `filter` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
Optional.ofNullable(Outer.getOuter)
        .filter(outer -> ::Objects.nonNull(outer.getInnerMethod()))
        .filter(SomethingElse::isAllowed)
        .map (.. ); //or whatever operation you want to do here
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` instead of `map`. From the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)

> *If a value is present, and the value matches the given predicate, return an Optional describing the value, otherwise return an empty Optional.*

```
Optional<Obj> optional = Optional.ofNullable(Outer.getOuter)
    .map(Outer::getInnerMethod)
    .filter(SomethingElse::isAllowed)
    .map(SomethingElse::getSomethingElse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using map to chech if it's allowed use `filter(e -> e.isAllowed())` this will filter out anything that isn't allowed.